# Finding an equation of a hyperplane given 2 lines

Tags: analysis, proof-verification, vectors, linear-transformations

So the book I'm using for my Intro. to Analysis class is *An introduction to Analysis* by William R. Wade, and I'm stuck on a problem and can't quite match my answer up with the one given in the book.  The question is

8.2.2 (b) *Find an equation of the hyperplane that contains the lines $\phi(t)=(t,t,t,1)$ and $\psi(t)=(1,t,1+t,t), t\in \mathbb{R}$.*

My Sol.  Note that $\phi(t)=\langle 1,1,1,0 \rangle t +\langle 0,0,0,1\rangle$ and $\psi(t)=\langle 0,1,1,1 \rangle t +\langle 1,0,1,0\rangle$.  Since both lines lie on the hyperplane, then the points $A(1,1,1,0), B(0,0,0,1), C(0,1,1,1)$ and $D(1,0,1,0)$ are on the hyperplane.  It follows that the vectors $\vec{AD}=\langle 0,-1,0,0\rangle, \vec{CD}=\langle 1,-1,0,-1\rangle$ and $\vec{BD}=\langle 1,0,1,-1\rangle$ are linearly independent vectors that lie on the hyperplane with normal

$\vec{b}=\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
e_1 & e_2 & e_3 & e_4       \\
0 & -1 & 0 & 0       \\
1 & -1 & 0 & -1       \\
1 & 0 & 1 & -1
\end{array}\right]=-e_1-e_4=\langle -1,0,0,-1\rangle.$

Since $\vec{b}\cdot A=-1$, then it follows that the *point-normal form* equation of the hyperplane is $x_1+x_4=1$, for $\vec{x}=\langle x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4\rangle$ in the hyperplane.

Wade claims that the equation is $x-y+w=1$.  Why is this the case?

Comment: Typo or mistake in : $\psi(t)=\langle 0,1,1,1\rangle t+ \langle 1,0,1,0\rangle$.

Comment: Thank you, I've correct it.

Comment: Why $A$ and $C$ are  points of the plane?

Comment: That was the issue... thanks, Emilio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Yours $A=\langle 1,1,1,0\rangle$ and $C=\langle 0,1,1,1\rangle$ are not points on the plane. They are the vectors that orient the lines.

Yours $B$ and $D$ are the points on the plane for $t=0$ and you need two other points, e.g. for $t=1$.

Than you can do the same work as in OP.